# Which parent table should my foreign key refer to?

Tags: database-design

I have two tables. `Department` and `Degree`. Department has many courses which they teach under some degree. Therefore, I can say that, a `Course` belongs to both a `Degree` and `Department`.

The question is, If I now define a `Course` table, which parent should I point through foreign key? Is it `Department` or it's child `Degree`?

Comment: If you didn't have a `degree` could the `department` still run `courses`?

Comment: imo, The `course` belongs to the `degree` and the `degree` to the `department`?

Comment: yes. and that way, a `course` belongs to the `department`

Comment: `courses` don't directly belong to a `department`. It is implied. If another department provided the same `degree` then they would also run the same `course`. i.e. You would run a query driving off  `degree` to find out which `departments` ran which `courses`?

Comment: @RyanVincent can you give an answer based on some research or standard?

Comment: Requirements: `Department` wants to run a `course`. Relationships:  1) `course`  must be linked directly to a `degree`.  2) `department` provides `degree` directly not `course`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91612/discussion-between-anwar-and-ryan-vincent).